# How do I compare the value of two crossings

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I have expressed this in every way I could think of and still no go... Im plotting the crossing ov two variables and want the value of the crossing labeled there as well. I can get it to do that however the next step is to compare it to the previous crossing, meaning if A and B cross = C...
Label C and tell me how much different it is from C[1].

If anyone could help I will be very grateful. Ive read the entire manual and //kodify.net/... In my head Im doing exactly as its saying to do, however I get an error...

here is the script I tried posting it here but I kept getting an error

click here for the script --->> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m3g8.png

Comment: Please provide your code as formatted text in your question and not an image. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Im not sure if you would see this but thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here we use [`valuewhen()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_valuewhen) to subtract the value of `k` at the previous cross from its value at the last cross:

```
//@version=4
study("Stochastic Slow Strategy")
length = input(14, minval=1)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)
xUp = crossover(k,d)
deltaX = valuewhen(xUp, k, 0) - valuewhen(xUp, k, 1)

if xUp
    label.new(bar_index, k, tostring(deltaX, "#.00"))

plot(k, "k", color.orange)
plot(d)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. that did it. that really helped.